# ImportError: cannot import name 'search' from 'googlesearch' in python

Tags: python-3.x, importerror, google-search, python-packaging, index-error

When I am importing google from googlesearch I am getting the following error.

`from googlesearch import search`

```
(...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\googlesearch\__init__.py)
ImportError: cannot import name 'search' from 'googlesearch' in python
```

I simply tried to run the entire googlesearch.py code from "...\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages\googlesearch\googlesearch.py". However, then I got the following error.

```
totalText = soup.select(GoogleSearch.TOTAL_SELECTOR)[0].children.__next__()

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you've confused these two libraries [googlesearch-python](https://pypi.org/project/googlesearch-python/) and [google-search](https://pypi.org/project/google-search/).

Most likely you've installed the second one but trying to use API from the first one.